# Display block without 100% width

Tags: html, css, width

I want to set a span element to appear below another element using the display property. I tried applying inline-block but without success, and figured I could use block if I somehow managed to avoid giving the element a width of 100% (I don't want the element to "stretch out"). Can this be done, or if not, what's good praxis for solving this kind of issue?

Example: a news list where I want to set a "read more" link at the end of each post (note: `<a>` instead of `<span>`)

```
<li>
<span class="date">11/15/2012</span>
<span class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
<a class="read-more">Read more</a> 
</li>
```

Update: Solved. In CSS, apply

```
li {
    clear: both;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Have you got any markup (HTML or CSS) to show us? It's difficult to work on the problem without anything to actually work on. Also a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be good.

Comment: Thought I didn't need any sample code since it's just about positioning a span element. See updated post.

Comment: You can seriously cut down on all that markup by just using just one line of code as I mentioned below.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, the following CSS will float your a below the spans and keep it from having a 100% width:

```
a {
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    clear: left; 
}
```

Comment: I tried applying this but since the span elements (title and date, in the example) doesn't have float the link gets positioned before the last span. Guess one solution would be to make all child elements in the li float.

Comment: This works if I apply a clearfix for the li parent. Will go with this solution, thanks PJ.

Answer (score 182):

Use

```
display: table
```

in your CSS code.

Comment: Genius solution. `margin: 0 auto;` if you need it centered.

Comment: `display: table;` works, but does not accept any padding.

Comment: @ha404 you are right, padding works! https://jsfiddle.net/wgj7xvLe/4/ at least in my browser (Chromium).

Comment: @donquixote it should accept padding as long as you use border-collapse: separate.  just had that problem.

Answer (score 65):

you can use:

`width: max-content;`

Note: support is limited, [check here](http://caniuse.com/#search=max-content) for a full breakdown of supporting browsers

Comment: I'd never heard of this! Interesting.

Comment: Was good since Chrome 46 and FF 66. Should be accepted answer. `inline-block` et al was breaking my layout.

Comment: @i336_ As of today it's still not supported by the Edge browser.

Comment: Edge, or Chromium Edge? (To be clear; the former is going to be transitioning out for quite a while...)

Comment: According to caniuse.com it is supported in Edge as of Edge 79 released Jan 14th, 2020.  In total has a 92% support rating. https://caniuse.com/?search=max-content This is a nice welcome to me. When I first heard about it almost 2 years ago it did not have wide enough support for me to use in production but now it does.

Comment: I have never heard of this rule and it is amazing

Comment: Thanks, (not only semantically) much better than obsolescent solutions like table-mimicing or floats. Or in the words of the populace: *“This should be the accepted answer”*.

Answer (score 9):

I would keep each row to its own div, so...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
</div>
```

And then for the CSS:

```
.cell{display:inline-block}
```

It's hard to give you a solution without seeing your original code.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer not to mix in any div elements.

Answer (score 6):

Again: an answer that might be a little bit too late (but for those who find this page for the answer anyways).

Instead of
`display:block;` use `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
li a {
    width: 0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the following:**

```
display: inline-block;
```

Works well on links and other elements.

Comment: This has the side effect of allowing elements to be laid out side by side, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

i use this:

vertical-align: top;  //do the trick

```
a {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 10px 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #372a20;
border: 1px solid var(--blanco); 
color: var(--blanco);
margin: 0 auto -25px;
text-decoration: none;
```

}