# How to create a block div that fits content width?

Tags: css, html

I have a div that contains a fixed width content (image inside another div) and a variable width content (text that changes dynamically). I need this outer div to:

- start from a new line
- be exactly as wide as its content
- preferably end in a new line

Because it should be the only element on the line, I can not use `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`. On the other hand, `display:block` does not auto-shrink. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/D9QV9/

My experiments with `overflow`, `float` and `clear` yielded no result. Any help, advice, link etc is very welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post up the relevant HTML and CSS please? Or even better, make a jsfiddle.net version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708381/display-block-without-100-width

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I did: I gave `#outer` the CSS-style `display:inline-block` and then simply put that in another div with the css `display:block` to make sure that `#outer` stayed on a separate line:

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}

#image {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
}

#element_block {
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
Some content above div

<div id="element_block">
    <div id="outer">
        Text inside div<div id="image">IMG</div>
    </div>
</div>

Some content below div
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D9QV9/1/)

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. I wonder, if the same effect can be attained by using one div, not two...

Comment: @Eques You can try using `display:table` or `width: intrinsic;` (the latter is unfortunately not supported by any IE at this moment). To me those two solutions required to put the text outside `#image` in a div and add `float:left;` or `float:right` to put all text on the same line, though.

Comment: If you can't get this to work (if it wraps lines instead of expanding to fit them) it could be because you have a floated element. It seems at least with Chrome, the width of calculated as if the float wasn't there.

Comment: For this reason, I ended up using "display: table" and "display: table-cell" instead of "display: inline-block" and floats.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I got this right for you, but I think this helps:

By placing

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

you can change middle into top, bottom, etc.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D9QV9/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `<br/>` between your 'text-element' and your 'block-element'.
Then display:inline-block your inner container

```
#outer {
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}

#image {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
}
```

[jsfiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/D9QV9/4/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but <br> is not good for my case. Depending on what I have before the <div> container, there might appear an extra vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

Use flex box:

```css
.holder{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}

.item{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="item">
    Item has a lot of text
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Small
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Very big and wide with lots of content
  </div>
</div>
```