# Display div as centered blocks without 100% width

Tags: css, width, block

I know it's a super-basic question, but I'm not able to find a solution. I have 2 div and I would like to display them as blocks (one below the other) without having 100% width. Here's my code.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="test">one</div>
    <div class="test">two</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test {
    display:inline-block;
    clear: both;
    border:1px solid;
}

#container {
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Unfortunately this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708381/display-block-without-100-width) doesn't fit to me, since I need to center blocks horizontally (so float cannot be applied in my case). Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8LuQ/1/). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why you're using `clear:both` in your CSS since nothing is floated. Plus, wouldn't a simple `<br />` between your divs do what you want?

Comment: You're right @j08691, `clear:both` is from the answer I cited. As first choise, I would like to avoid adding extra html (like `<br/>`) but style everything with CSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b8LuQ/4/ and <br /> isn't really centered ^^

Comment: @ReeCube - You have white space in your code that is factored into the centering. Remove it and you'll see that it centers.

Comment: @j08691 ah you're right, ok then i think it's a good solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to center them on top of each other without taking 100% `width` and still use `margin:auto;` use : `display:table;`

```
.test {
display:table;
margin:auto;
border:solid;/* to see it */
}
```

Comment: The only drawback with this approach is compatibility with older versions of IE.

Comment: I think you got it, @GCyrillus! That's what I was looking for. Nice note also from @j08691 but as stated in this [compatibility page](http://caniuse.com/css-table), the proposed syntax is compatible with IE8, which is my goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the width of the divs, change `display` to `block`, and use `margin: 0 auto` to center them.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxx92/)

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to define a width

Comment: As correctly stated from @oGeez, I don't know the width of blocks but I would like each block to adapt to its content. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem! Seems like @GCyrillus is up to something :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also center the div by adding 50% left offset, and then negative margin in amount to half width of the div. I do not know how much is this applicable to your case, but here is an example:

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid;
    width: 300px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/b8LuQ/7/

Comment: This can be a way, but I don't want to declare fixed widths. Divs should adapt to their contents.

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline-block;` is not allow the second line. Therefore I removed it and define width for both div test one two you can resize it and `margin:auto` is align center the both div in container here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/2ph9a/)