# cross out a text and pay attention to the maximum width of the container

Tags: html, css

I would like to cross out a text within a `span`. Currently I have this

```css
.content {}

.pending {}

.closed {
  position: relative;
}

.closed::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content pending">
  this is a text about foo
</div>

<div class="content closed">
  this is a text about bar
</div>
```

How can I limit the border to the current content? I only want to cross out the text, not the full container.

I don't want to use the `<s>` tag because I would like to style the line.

Maybe there is completely different way to solve this?

Comment: Try `display: table;` on `.closed`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708381/display-block-without-100-width for more.

Comment: `inline-block` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the inner text in a data-attribute, the following would be a hackish approach that would work in certain scenarios:

```css
.content {}

.pending {}

.closed {
  position: relative;
}

.closed::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-text);
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block; /* makes sure ::before's width is determined by its content */
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* makes the text invisible */
}
```

```html
<div class="content pending">
  this is a text about foo
</div>

<div class="content closed" data-text="this is a text about bar">
  this is a text about bar
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set your `.closed` to `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`

```css
.content {}

.pending {}

.closed {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.closed::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content pending">
  this is a text about foo
</div>

<div class="content closed">
  this is a text about bar
</div>
```

Comment: inline-block would be better

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacky way that rely on flexbox trick but you won't have transparency:

```css
.closed {
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
}
/*fill the remaining space and hide the before*/
.closed::after {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:1;
  background:#fff;
  height:1em;
  z-index:1;
}
/**/
.closed::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content pending">
  this is a text about foo
</div>

<div class="content closed">
  this is a text about bar
</div>
```

Or simply add a span inside if you can adjust the HTML:

```css
.closed span{
  position: relative;
}

.closed span::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content pending">
  this is a text about foo
</div>

<div class="content closed">
  <span>this is a text about bar</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, adding:

```
width:fit-content;
```

should cross out the word

Comment: Currently the support for `fit-content` is quite limited: https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content